# How to resolve "ERROR: Failed to resolve: com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:19.1"?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am working on my first Android application with firebase by self_studying with some tutorials to get started with.
Now, I was trying to set the user path by following these steps.

1. Choose a sign-in method (Email/Password)
2. Go to Docs -> Copy Gradle dependency line (Authentication) which was `com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:19.1.0`
3. Paste on build.gradle(Module:App) under dependencies as `implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:19.1.0'`
4. Sync the project

The issue is when I synced the project following error occurs.

```
ERROR: Failed to resolve: com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:19.1
Show in Project Structure dialog
Affected Modules: app
```

Can anyone help me to resolve this error?

P.S. I saw some post which having the same issue but in different versions. Answers for those were with the version changings. That's why I'm asking for a more specific solution.

Comment: Add your project-level `build.gradle` file

Comment: did you mean the JSON file? I already added to the app file in my project folder.

Comment: Not the JSON file. Show your root-level (project-level) `build.gradle` file

Comment: If you are interested in a clean Firebase authentication, you can check this [article](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-create-a-clean-firebase-authentication-using-mvvm-37f9b8eb7336).